# Extremely basic question about namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, name-lookup, using-directives, using-declaration

```
using namespace X;
    cout << var;
    using Y::var;
    cout << var;
```

So say I have a namespace X and a namespace Y that both contain a variable of type int called var. When I say `using namespace X;` what I imagine happening is if I use some variable that isn't in the global namescope what basically happens is it goes okay I'm gonna look for var in `namespace X` but now that I also use `Y::var` what does this exactly mean? Does that just say var is the same as Y::var? But then in that case what's happening with `using namespace X` does it not even look for var in there because I said I'm using `Y::var`?

Comment: Just create an example and check what compiler will do. This is best way to learn. If we serve you an answer you will forget it in 5 minutes.

Comment: Depends on context. Create a [mcve]. Instead of describing how the program is, show us the program.

Comment: There's a program that can answer these types of questions. [You can ask it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Tca744nnK)

Comment: I already did check what the compiler did and I got what I expected which is using namespace X I printed var and I got the var inside that namespace  then when I used Y::var and printed that out I got the var inside the Y namespace I just want to ask to make sure is what I said before right? Me saying I'm using Y:::var kind of just overwrites using namespace X kind of? At least for var sorry if I'm not explaining this well but when I say I'm using Y::var is that basically saying ok ignore that other namespace I'm using if you see var in the code I'm talking about Y::var?

Comment: "_I'm using Y:::var kind of just overwrites using namespace X kind of?_" - It only overrides it for `X::var`. The rest of `X` is still used.

Comment: Yeah I said at least for var right after that thanks I basically understood this already I just wanted to make sure I was thinking of it the right way thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the using directive

```
using namespace X;
```

the compiler uses the unqualified name lookup to find the name `var` used in the following statement

```
cout << var;
```

And due to the using directive it will find the variable `var` in the namespace `X`.

This using declaration

```
using Y::var;
```

introduces the variable `var` from the namespace `Y` in the current scope and the next statement

```
cout << var;
```

will use the variable `var` from the namespace `Y`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X
{
    int var = 1;
}

namespace Y
{
    int var = 2;
}

int main() 
{
    using namespace X;

    std::cout  << "var = " << var << '\n';

    using Y::var;

    std::cout  << "var = " << var << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
var = 1
var = 2
```

That is the using declaration that introduces the variable `var` in the block scope of the function main hides the declaration of the variable `var` declared in the namespace `X`.

In fact the below simplified demonstration program in essence behaves similarly as the above program relative to the name lookup.

```
#include <iostream>

int var = 1;

int main() 
{
    std::cout  << "var = " << var << '\n';

    int var = 2;

    std::cout  << "var = " << var << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `using Y::var;` does hide `X::var` when you ask for `var`. The former is as-if `Y::var` were declared in this scope, the latter only influences unqualified lookup.

> `using ns_name::name;`
>
> [*using-declaration*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations): makes the symbol `name` from the namespace `ns_name` accessible for unqualified lookup as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this *using-declaration* appears.

> Names introduced into a namespace scope by a *using-declaration* can be used just like any other names, including qualified lookup from other scopes

> `using namespace ns_name;`
>
> [*using-directive*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives): From the point of view of unqualified name lookup of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, every name from `ns_name` is visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and `ns_name`.